# Disabling the hint window that EClipse Editor shows

Tags: eclipse

when I hover over the codes in ECLispe Editor it pops up this yellow hint box for everything that I am on it to show some useful info about it. well it is cool but it is also annoying! is there a way that I can deactivate it as Default setting and then anytime I needed it I hit a hot-key to bring it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go:
Window->Preferences

In the tree look for "Hovers" under Java->Editor->Hovers

You can uncheck all the ones you do not want, or add keyboard shortcuts to activate a Hover. Not particularly useful, but may help.